# how to make request to LinkedIn API v2 and OAuth 2.0 without JS SDK?

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I'm trying to integrate LinkedIn v2 OAuth 2.0 login directly from the browser, but in order to Ovid Cross-Origin issues, I need to use JS SDK.

but I saw here: 
https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates

that from the 1 of March js SDK will not work

> SDKs: Our JavaScript and Mobile Software Development Kits (SDKs) will stop
>   working. Developers will need to migrate to using OAuth 2.0 directly from 
>   their apps.

so how can I make login with LinkedIn if there is no SDK any more?? (and I can't use any non-free or non-commercial OAuth lib)

and also am trying to avoid using server side for that

Comment: If they don’t offer any purely client-based login flow any more, then you will have to use a server … The exchange code for token step requires your client secret, and you do not want to expose that in client-side code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution for the V1 API. I am not sure if this will be continued or not in V2 of the API.

You can create a URL with the parameters as follows, however there are some issues with the `image` and `summary` fields showing up as expected.

- `page` - URL of Page
- `title` - Page Content
- `summary` - Summary of content
- `source` - Name of Site

Construct the URL as such: (interpolated string example)

`https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=${page}&title=${title}&summary=${summary}&source=${source}`

It is recommended, if you control the html metatags to apply the following for a richer experience in sharing.

```
  <meta property="og:title" content="My Shared Article Title" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="Description of shared article" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/my_article.html" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/foo.jpg" />
```

#### SOURCE:

[Linked In - Share on LinkedIn V1 Docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin)

#### TypeScript Example

This example creates a new window with the share link.

```
let page = this.getPageUrl(true);
let title = this.getTagTitle(true);
let summary = this.getTagDescription(true);
let source = this.getTitle(true);

let tokenLink = `https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=${page}&title=${title}&summary=${summary}&source=${source}`;

window.open(tokenLink);
```

Comment: thank you for your comment but currently, you will need js SDK to implement what you mention but as I said, the SDK is going to be deprecated in 1 of March.

Comment: This does not require the JavaScript SDK.